# html unit load page with modernizr(error)

Tags: javascript, htmlunit, modernizr

i have code where i use htmlUnit(2.4 version) to load page which use modernizr. And i catch exception within load page, error move from modernizr. This exception well break all events or this is local error to modernizr and all is ok and all events(for page) will be executed?

or this may be common problem of modernizr(and reason not in htmlUnit) and in pc browser this catched in try catch blocks?

Here is my stacktrace
http://pastebin.ru/OU1Dl0MV

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the current version of HtmlUnit (2.15 as of today) or even better the latest snapshot (https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_QuickBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts).
And if the problem persists, please open a issue in the projects bugtracker (https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/).

From a first look the problem (exception) should not occur with the current source code (2.16-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: 2.15 more older than 2.4 version?)

Comment: have a look at the [change history](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html), this states things clearly